# Better ways of hiding a fragment container?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

noob fragmentmanager question. Is there a better way to close a fragment from a button inside said fragment? I was trying to use getParentFragmentManager from within the fragment in the onclick but this doesnt seem to work(or do anything really). Im guessing because I really need the container in the main activity to be hidden and not the fragment? I do have a working viewModel and was wondering if it would be better to run a co-routine in the main activity that listens for the button click and hides/shows the fragment in the container view. Keep in mind I have multiple container views in the main activity.

```
parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(this).commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use supportFragmentManager instead of parentFragmentManager(if not using fragment inside fragment) guessing that your activity is AppCompat one.

```
activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(this).commit()
```

or if you want to pop your fragment then you can do the following:

```
activity.supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

To hide from activity, we can use fragmentlistener callback. It's a callback kind of:

```
public class MyActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener {
@Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String pageClassName, int operationCode, Bundle operationRequirement) {
       //here we can put conditions if any according to pageClassName or operationCode
    }

}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    /**
     * @param pageClassName This basically class.getName() string eg.Myfragment.this.getClass().getName()
     * @param operationCode This would be an we are using to distinguish each opearation
     * @param operationRequirement This would be bundle that would contain result
     * */
    void onFragmentInteraction(String pageClassName, int operationCode, @Nullable Bundle operationRequirement);
}
```

Now inside my fragment:

```
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;



@Override
    public void onAttach(@NotNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) mActivity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("activity must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

now inside onClick of fragment:

```
  mListener.onFragmentInteraction(TAG, HIDE_FRAMENT, extras);
```

Comment: Correct, MainActivitiy extends AppCompatActivity and has a few different container views in them. I'm using saved preferences to determine if this is the first start of the app and displaying a fragment if so. Only issue is trying to hide that container via the button's on click method. Tried both of those lines but I think they only work in the main activity? Should I use the viewmodel to communicate from the fragment to the main activity that the button was clicked?

Comment: While this did seem like a working solution, I ended up using Navigation component. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation

Comment: I don't understand how it is related to Navigation

Answer (score 0):

Navigation component appears to be the best way (for my use case) to manage fragment transactions. Works with binding also!

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation